# No Emgucv ImageBox when using Emgucv with VisualStudio 2019

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I cannot find the Emgucv ImageBox after installing Emgucv.runtime.windows through the NuGet packages manager. I have also tried and failed looking for the Emgucv dll files in the .NET framework components list as a potential work-around (found by right clicking on 'Choose items ...' under the general toolbox).

I'm trying to access my webcam using VB.net and need to show the image frame preferably in the Emgucv ImageBox rather than the standard .NET framework PictureBox.

Is there a reason why I cannot find the Emgucv ImageBox?

Here's my code snippet:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim imageCapture As Emgu.CV.VideoCapture = New Emgu.CV.VideoCapture
    Dim image_mat As Mat = New Mat
    Dim img As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Bgr, Byte)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        REM things get messy here.... 
        image_mat = Me.imageCapture.QueryFrame
        img = image_mat.ToImage(Of Bgr, Byte)

        REM I want to convert img into a compatible data type for the PictureBox1.Image since I do not have the Emgucv ImageBox

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you add a Project Reference to the `Emgu.CV.Platform.NetFramework.dll` assembly? Do you have, among the References, the `Emgu.CV` and `Emgu.CV.runtime.windows` assemblies references? In case you don't, add a reference to the former assembly by browsing to the Project's `\bin\debug` folder. If you already do have these and the `Emgu.CV` tab still doesn't appear in the Toolbox, then clean and rebuild the Solution, restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, check in `NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` whether you have updates for the Emgu.CV package, since it requires an updated `System.Drawing.primitives` assembly, which comes from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is an alternative to using the imageBox tool. In the Nuget Package Manager there is an additional Emgu framework for converting Emgu.CV.Mat data types into Bitmap - it's called Emgu.CV.Bitmap.

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim imageCapture As Emgu.CV.VideoCapture = New Emgu.CV.VideoCapture
    Dim image_mat As Emgu.CV.Mat = New Emgu.CV.Mat
    Dim img As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Bgr, Byte)

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        image_mat = Me.imageCapture.QueryFrame
        img = image_mat.ToImage(Of Bgr, Byte)
        PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap REM <---------

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're leaking a giant amount of graphics resources. For example, the first line in the Timer.Tick handler should be `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()`. But you should use a Bitmap Field.

Comment: Thank you Jimi for your help - I appreciate it